# How to call a user defined function in vba code

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I created a Public function in Module two called `"t_value"`. I now want to use this function in the VBA code for a userform, which uses the input from the userform.

This is the function:

```
Public Function t_value(theta As Variant)
    Dim theta_1 As Integer, theta_2 As Integer
    Dim A As Variant, B As Variant, s As Variant

    theta_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(theta, 5)
    theta_2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(theta, 5)
    A = theta - theta_1
    B = theta_2 - theta_1
    s = A / B
    t_value = s

End Function
```

Here is the code I would like to use the function above in:

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()
    Dim theta As Variant, alpha As Variant, t As Variant, u As Variant

    theta = UserForm1.theta_input.Value
    alpha = UserForm1.alpha_input.Value
    t = Application.WorksheetFunction.t_value(theta)

End Sub
```

Normally `"Application.WorksheetFunction.[function]"` works, but it wouldn't work for me in this situation - I thought it may be due to the fact I created the formula. Would it be easier to just put the formula into the Sub? I was worried about runtime. I'm rather new, so I'm not completely familiar with VBA syntax.

Comment: Why do you expect your function to be available under predefined `Application.WorksheetFunction`? If you put it in a module, simply call it `t_value(theta)`.

Comment: That's just how I've recalled (predefined) functions in the past. I was not aware how it may be different for a module. Thanks for the help!

Comment: ++ good quality first question :) cheers & welcome to StackOverflow.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Application.WorksheetFunction` is a class defined in the `Excel` library; you can find it in the *Object Browser* (F2):

[image: object browser showing WorksheetFunction class]

A public `Function` in a standard module is just a function that can be invoked from a worksheet cell (provided it doesn't have *side-effects*), just as well as from anywhere in the workbook's VBA project: you can't write any VBA code that "becomes a member" of a class that's defined in a library you're referencing.

So if you have a function called `MyFunction` in a module called `Module1`, you can invoke it like this:

```
foo = MyFunction(args)
```

Or like this:

```
foo = Module1.MyFunction(args)
```

So in this case:

```
t = t_value(theta)
```

> *Would it be easier to just put the formula into the Sub?*

Nope, because a `Sub` won't *return* a value (however, you can pass variables `ByRef`):

```
Sub t_value(theta as variant, ByRef t as Variant)

Dim theta_1 As Integer, theta_2 As Integer
Dim A As Variant, B As Variant, s As Variant

theta_1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Floor(theta, 5)
theta_2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.Ceiling(theta, 5)
A = theta - theta_1
B = theta_2 - theta_1
s = A / B
t = s   '## Assign the value to the ByRef 't' variable and it should retain its value in the calling procedure
End Sub
```

Whether you choose to put this function in a module (`Public`) or in the user form module is a design decision that depends on whether you want the function to be generally available outside of the form instance(s).  Whether you choose to make this function a `sub` is a bit different -- I'd probably recommend against it following the general best practice that Functions should *return* values and Subroutines should just perform actions and/or manipulate objects.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I really appreciate it!

Answer (score 4):

Directly use 

`t = t_value(theta)`
 
, instead of 

`t = Application.WorksheetFunction.t_value(theta)`